# What is a terminal wrapper?

Tags: linux

In my linux mint 13 xfce install I was creating a keyboard shortcut for gnome-terminal when I came across another binary called `gnome-terminal.wrapper`.

xfce4-terminal also has an equivalent `xfce4-terminal.wrapper` binary.

What is the purpose of the .wrapper extension? The man pages don't seem to say anything about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The wrapper makes the command-line arguments of **xfce4-terminal** (or **gnome-terminal**) consistent with the arguments for **(u)xterm**.  This way the app can serve as a drop-in replacement for xterm when invoked from other applications.

For example, it can be used by **clusterssh** (`terminal=/usr/bin/xfce4-terminal.wrapper`), and your favorite desktop's *"run command in terminal"* feature if you change your default terminal application.

Answer (score -1):

Run the `file` command on that `gnome-terminal.wrapper` (or other) file, you'll find out it is some (e.g. Perl) script. Look into that script, you'll guess it is translating some arguments....